# How does the voltage at the R4(1) point become 3.78V?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

How to calculate the voltage between R4 & R3? I got that due to the two 10k resistors there's a voltage divider happening which causes the point between R1 & R2 to be at 2.5V. But then doesn't the voltage across the two 100k resistors become: (Assuming that the source is 5V)

5-2.5 = 2.5V ?

And then the voltage between R4 & R3 become:

1.25V

according to voltage divider equation?

What am I getting wrong here?

[image: Circuit Diagram of the resistor circuit]

Comment: R3 and R4 are in parallel with R1 - that changes the voltage divider.

Comment: 200K across R1 pulls R1(2) up above 2.5V. The rest follows...

Comment: In other words, your assumption that R1 and R2 form an ideal voltage divider is not correct.

Comment: Redraw the circuit with the +5V points connected together and see where that takes you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redrawing the circuit can make what's going on a little bit clearer. Just as Peter wrote, you can see here that R1 is in parallel with R3 and R4, so the voltage divider formula, in this case, would be helpful only after you reduce R1, R3 and R4 to their equivalent resistance. Call it Req, and then try to use the voltage divider formula. After that, you'd know what the voltage is across R2, and it would be possible to calculate the voltage on R3 and R4 individually. I'm sure you can follow it up from here :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fucHFG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>